# How to preserve line returns when copying multi-line text between single and multi-line Ace Editor instances

Tags: javascript, formatting, ace-editor

We have a UI where we present a small, single-line Ace editor instance which allows the user to quickly write a short, simple query using our custom mode.

We have just added the ability to open a dialog containing a larger, multi-line editor, which allows the user to write larger, more complex queries.

However, when closing the editor and copying the text back to the single-line editor, the carriage returns are stripped, and if the user re-opens the multi-line popup, all of their formatting is gone...

Is there any way, maybe via something like custom tokens, to identify a carriage return (/r/n) so that it renders as an empty space in the single-line editor, but renders as a hard-return in the multi-line version?

Thanks!

[image: Multiline]
[image: Single line]

Comment: So you want to convert all the linebreaks (/r/n) to space and show on a single line and then again convert those spaces to line breaks to show on your multi-line editor mode?

Comment: yes... that's exactly it... we use custom tokens for things like "left open bracket" / "peLeftParen"... is there someway possible to create a new token for a "breaking space"?